# How to: create a basic page by code and fill its CEWP with content?

Tags: 2013, content-editor-web-part, web-part-page

I have to migrate some content from text files from my storage to my SharePoint 2013.

The plan is to put the content into some content editor webparts at a basic page.

I know how to create the basic pages like items in my doclib via a console app, but how do i get the CEWP for adding some content to it?

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet could help you. This can be achieved using **SPLimitedWebPartManager**.
Pass your required page url to "pageURL" in the code below.

```
SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(pageURL, System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
             XmlElement p = new XmlDocument().CreateElement("p");
             p.InnerText = "<b>Hello World</b>";
             ContentEditorWebPart editor = new ContentEditorWebPart(){ Content = p};
             mgr.AddWebPart(editor, "Header", 1);
             spWebTest.Update();
```